# Zoom in and out changing the position of the radio button

Tags: css

How can I fix the problem when zooming in and out(e.g. 80%) the checked radio button is slightly changing the position of the dot in the radio button?
Tried position fixed but it didn't help.Something to do with width and height probably but I can't figure out.

This is how it looks after zooming out

[image]

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  width              : 20px;
  height             : 20px;
  border-radius      : 50%;
  /* outline         : none; */
  border             : 3px solid gray;
  }
input[type="radio"]:before {
  content       : "";
  display       : block;
  width         : 60%;
  height        : 60%;
  margin        : 20% auto;
  border-radius : 50%;
  }
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  background   : green;
  }
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color : green;
  }
.role {
  margin-right : 80px;
  margin-left  : 20px;
  font-weight  : normal;
  }
.checkbox label {
  margin-bottom : 20px !important;
  }
.roles {
  margin-bottom : 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="ONE" id="one" />
  <label class="role" for="one">ONE</label>
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="TWO" id="two" />
  <label class="role" for="two">TWO</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks more like a technical problem due to the low number of pixels available...

Comment: Looks like it, I tried it on better screen and didn't see the problem on the most zoom outs and zoom ins but could see it on one.
How is it possible to avoid it from happening on other screen types?

Comment: even if you use an svg image while hiding the control, this "defect" will not go away: it is a graphics chip and screen quality problem.

Comment: so there is no problem in css? Because I have a similar example without this problem

Comment: It's not the kind of css I would use for this design, but otherwise I don't see any problem in your css code.

Comment: could you maybe give me an example I should use(you would use) instead of the current design?

Comment: [there is plenty](https://freefrontend.com/css-radio-buttons/) ! one of them :  https://codepen.io/jkantner/pen/rNaPadg

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, using `display:flex` for class roles and `align-items:center` for aligning vertically

Sample working code below and codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rNrgeOx for reference -

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  width              : 20px;
  height             : 20px;
  border-radius      : 50%;
  /* outline         : none; */
  border             : 3px solid gray;
  }
input[type="radio"]:before {
  content       : "";
  display       : block;
  width         : 60%;
  height        : 60%;
  margin        : 20% auto;
  border-radius : 50%;
  }
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  background   : green;
  }
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color : green;
  }
.role {
  margin-right : 80px;
  margin-left  : 20px;
  font-weight  : normal;
  }
.checkbox label {
  margin-bottom : 20px !important;
  }
.roles {
  margin-bottom : 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="ONE" id="one" />
  <label class="role" for="one">ONE</label>
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="TWO" id="two" />
  <label class="role" for="two">TWO</label>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but it is still aligning to the left or right after zooming out

Comment: Did you try in fullscreen mode from codepen ..it looks fine - https://codepen.io/nagasai/full/rNrgeOx

Comment: yeap I did, opened codepen and zoomed out on chrome browser

Comment: it moving left and right like eye

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **transform** **scale** property in this case. Replace **before** css with below code:

```
input[type="radio"]:before {
  content       : "";
  display       : block;
  width         : 100%;
  height        : 100%;
  border-radius : 50%;
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
```